# Forcing the modification of a particular object and any extensions to be atomic

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking

I have a bit of a reader/writer problem.

I have a static collection of particular objects which can be accessed by many readers and writers at the same time.

The writers will obtain an item from the collection handler, and then modify it in some manner.

The readers may obtain that particular item from the collection handler and then display it in some manner.

Now I realise the standard solution to this problem is to create a lock (or a ReaderWriter one) and force each writer and reader to enter the lock. The problem is that I'm not the only one adding readers/writers, and so there is the chance that someone may forget to use the lock in their implementation and break everything.

So is there a way, from an object's side, to force all changes to be made in an atomic manner? Bear in mind that this object WILL be extended in multiple forms, and they must also be restrained in this manner.

Comment: Can you make the items immutable?

Comment: So similar to strings? Somehow detect there's a change, destroy the old object and link to the new one? It'll be too slow for my wishes unfortunatly, there is goig to be a ton of reading/writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the consumers of your objects cannot be trusted to obey safety rules then you have a big problem. I can see two solutions:

1) Do nothing. If your consumers write broken code then the pain they find themselves in will be a good incentive towards not doing that again.

1a) You can make their pain more excruciating by, say, having your object somehow detect when it is being read without a read lock and throwing an exception. This is what we did when designing the threading rules for the JScript and VBScript engines; if the user ever calls a method on a thread that does not support that method then the engines return the "catestrophic failure" error code. Users of the engine do not make that mistake twice; they very quickly learn which is the right thread and which is the wrong thread, and stop calling on the wrong thread.

This is a much better solution than simply allowing the call to succeed most of the time and then die with some crazy race condition problem one time in a million.

2) Move the responsibility for obtaining the lock into the object. Let the consumers use the object normally; the object takes out its own reader-writer lock whenever it is read or written.

Comment: How exactly would 2) work with modifying object in the collection (which was mentioned in the question)? Something like `ModifyAt(int index, Action<T> modification)`?

Comment: 1a) Throwing an exception would be a good solution, but I have no idea how to make the object detect that. Regarding 2) I am assuming you want me to put the lock in all the getters/setters of the property. While that would work (time consuming as it sounds) - the moment someone extends the object (and this object WILL be extended tons of times in various branches) I will lose the protection.

Comment: @Haedrian: One way to resolve that issue: The function that takes the lock is public but not virtual.  The extension point is a virtual protected function and is called by the public function.